# convert data to timeseries in R

Tags: r, time-series

How to convert following data to timeseries in R:

```
time   value
0       1
0.25    2
0.5     5
0.75    8
```

Comment: Maybe `as.ts(data)`..?

Comment: More robust `zoo::zoo(df$value, df$time)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
foo <- data.frame(time = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75), value = c(1, 2, 5, 8))
foo_ts <- as.ts(foo, start = 0, end = 0.75)
```